# Changing to a different active directory domain

Tags: 22.04

We have Ubuntu Linux machines connected to our Active Directory domain and need to move them to a different domain.  With this change, the domain user names will be changing as well.

It seems like the steps would be to leave the current domain and then join the new domain.

For example we currently have user1 connected to domain1.  That user will become user200 on domain2.

How do we keep user1 data and files accessible for user200?  Will the user account be deleted when we leave domain1?  Will we turn user1 account into a local account?  Can we turn it into a local account?

Thanks.